# Is it possible to get cypress to .visit() an xml page?

Tags: xml, cypress

The newest version of the app I'm testing is using xml instead of pure html.  Cypress doesn't seem to be able to render xml applications.  When I try to run a test the chrome window jsut shows a red-outlined error message box with the following text: "This page contains the following errors: error on line 3 at column 745: xmlParseEntityRef: no name"

The app loads just fine in chrome outside of cypress, which leads me to believe cypress either (a) cypress doesn't support xml or (b) there is in fact an xml error that chrome on it's own can handle gracefully but cypress cannot.

Anyone else have an insight into this?  Or can anyone confirm that cypress just doesn't support xml?  I don't see any mention of xml in the cypress docs.

Answer (score 0):

To Run cypress against an xml app you will have to edit a cypress file found on a (window's) path similar to:

`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.3.1\Cypress\resources\app\packages\runner\dist\injection.js`

Add blank lines before and after the single (long) line of code.  On the first blank line add `//<![CDATA[`.  On the last line put `//]]>`.  This more or less causes this code not to be executed as xml and then you can run your cypress tests against it!  Not totally sure what this injection file does to be honest, but I believe it can still be used by cypress.  The CDATA tags seems to just tell the browser that this injected code shouldn't be interpreted as xml, per this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784200/5020619).  If anyone else has more insight, please share!